# Trying to connect iOS app to dropbox, where do i get the app key this error refers to?

Tags: ios, dropbox-api

[ERROR] DropboxSDK: unable to link; app isn't registered for correct URL scheme (db-INSERT_APP_KEY)

On the dropbox website it states: "In the URL Schemes enter db-APP_KEY (replacing APP_KEY with the key generated when you created your app)."

Not sure what this key is or how to get it, help please??

Comment: Go to the App Console on the Dropbox developer page.

Comment: More specifically, the App Console is here: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps.

Comment: Ok thanks I've got it now. No longer getting the error but there is still no message asking if I want to link dropbox when I load my app?
I'm just using the tutorial code they have up, is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: It sounds like you should post a new question. Be sure to include the relevant code, what you were expecting, and what actually happened.